# Confusing "[ts] Type ... is not assignable to type [2322]" errors inside constrained generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've been puzzling over a TypeScript compiler error 2322 in the code below.

```
function broken<A extends {a: number}>() {
  const foo: A = {a: 1};  // unexpected error: [ts] Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type 'A'. [2322]
  console.log (foo);
}
```

Similar code compiles without errors if the type is non-generic.

```
function works() {
  interface A {a: number};
  const foo: A = {a: 1};  // no compiler error, as expected
  console.log (foo);
}
```

Why does the first function fail to compile?  I assume I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about the difference between interfaces and generic constraints.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vqx75yqx13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a while I realized the problem. Translating TypeScript error 2322 into plain English, it means: "*You're trying to set the value of `A`, which has a numeric property `a` **but which may also have additional properties (!!!)**, to an object literal that has only a numeric property `a`. Because this object literal lacks the other (potential) properties of A, the assignment fails.*"

As an illustration of the problem, imagine substituting A with a real type:

```
interface A { a: number; b: string; };
const foo: A = { a: 1 };  // compiler error, as expected
```

The compiler throws an error if any of the possible types that meet the generic constraint ("has a numeric property `a`") would work if the generic type was a specific type.

In theory, TypeScript could be smarter in cases like this by checking to see if the resulting `foo` can possibly cause problems later in the code. For example, if the only thing you do with `foo` is to use its `a` property and you don't return do any things to `foo` that go beyond its constraint, like passing it to other functions that accept `A`.

But it seems like TypeScript isn't that smart yet-- it doesn't look into the future of your code. Instead, it checks at the point of assignment whether all possible right-hand-side types meet the constraint of the left-hand-side type. If not, it throws an error.

If you're sure that the code won't cause a problem (e.g. because the value you passed in doesn't just extend `A`, it actually *is* an instance of `A`) then you can cast the value to A and the assignment will work.  This is a common pattern when calling external APIs like databases, which might return untyped JSON that you can cast to a type you know it will be. Like this:

```
function alsoWorks1<A extends {a: number}>() {
  const foo: A = {a: 1} as A;
  console.log (foo);
}
```

Or you could decide to change this from a generic function to a non-generic one.  Like this:

```
function alsoWorks2() {
  const bar = { a: 1 };
  const foo = { a: bar.a }; // no error
  console.log (foo);
}
```

Comment: I add a similar problem and I can't get my head around the solution. For me, this should be a Typescript bug. You are defining a constraint on the return type of your function. If the type of the returned variable effectively respect that constraint, that's it. It should compile. In no way this code would bring an undefined behavior and the `as A` that you add to your line should be unnecessary. This code should fail to compile ONLY IF the effective type provided to the function contains more than just the defined constraint. And it should fail at the call site, not in the function definition.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions and was having trouble. I needed to remove the __typename fields that Apollo automatically adds: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/6 but then was getting the `ts(2322)` error. Casting as number finally worked: `const lat: number = mapOptions.center.lat as number;
  const lng: number = mapOptions.center.lng as number;
  const mapOptionsCleaned = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng({ lat, lng }),
    zoom: mapOptions.zoom,
  };` I