# Why does the compiler complain about this Partial<T>

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I might be missing something here, but I don't understand why the following code isn't valid:

```
interface TestType {
  id: string;
}

interface TestConstraint<T extends TestType> {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly rawData: Partial<T>
}

class GenericClass<T extends TestType> implements TestConstraint<T> {
  readonly id: string;

  constructor(
    rawData: T
  ) {
    this.id = rawData.id;
  }

  get rawData(): Partial<T> {
    return {
        id: this.id,
    };
    // return {
    //     id: this.id,
    // } as Partial<T>;
  }
}
```

The compiler is returning an error:

```
Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.(2322)
```

That seems weird because that's roughly the definition of the TestType.

[Playground with the code above.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5lQTwA4oDeAUMmcsACYBcyWUoA5gNzEC%20xxoksiK6WAMIB7EPTjcAPKmQQAHpBCUMaTNnwQAfMhLlkUCHEqiANjgo06YBiBalyBo6fNQ4AdwAicMHFoAFOCgwYDgTaU12TgQTOAwVAHEIEGhgBEEYuOlZBSTlVSxcAm1gAFs8EwgSpLAVATARMWsJcHCdezJHYxAzC1p6JlZ25ARRegBXBDBhKAAKIb1XT29fNCGASja9PTAAC2AMADoqZABefXcvHyPKVj0OIcYIMHOlnxm1-0Dg0NbdLY6nmMoCBNv8tlRaLt9tcADTzchsW5ggD0yP0gOBoP%20qPBlihhyocLByBxbGQsWQASCITCqE0SLIHA4ZCAA)

Comment: Check out this answer, might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54610446/19902261